# AAC format Audio Streaming in iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, aac

I am developing an iPad application that streams audio from a radio station. I can stream MPEG format audio without any problem. But, I cannot stream AAC format data where as this works in the sample created for iPhone with same source.

Does anyone knows what is the problem here? However, I cannot attach the code snippet here since it contains quite few lines of code.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deepa

Comment: When I tried to debug the read-stream callback was getting called; but, AudioFileStream_PropertyListenerProc callback was not getting called. In read-stream callback first time byteRead was x bytes, next time it is 0. Why is that?

Comment: I also noticed that in read-stream callback I get the following error:The resource requested is forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem here. Actually the audio format that I was trying to stream was AACP not AAC and AACP support is broken in iPhone 2.1.

Please refer the following link:

http://www.mymacbd.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=26&p=3

Regards,
Deepa

Comment: I got the answer from the link mentioned in my Answer